# Binding variables to different data types in case of 'or' in the rule LHS

Tags: drools

**How can I bind variables to different types of facts matched in an `or` group in the rule LHS ?**

For instance, if I have the following rule-file:

```
package com.sample

rule "Rule1"
    when
         object1: ObjectType1( id == 1) or
         object2: ObjectType2( id == 2)
    then
        System.out.println(object1.getId());
        System.out.println(object2.getId());
end
```

and I use this driver code:

```
package com.sample;

import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;

public class DroolsTest {

  public static final void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      String ruleFilePath = "src/main/resources/rules/ruleFile.drl";
      KieSession kSession = KSessionUtil.buildKSession(ruleFilePath);

      ObjectType1 o1 = new ObjectType1(1);
      ObjectType2 o2 = new ObjectType2(2);

      kSession.insert(o1);
      kSession.insert(o2);

      kSession.fireAllRules();

      System.out.println("Bye");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

***`ObjectType1.java`***:

```
package com.sample;

public class ObjectType1 {
  public ObjectType1(int i) {
    super();
    this.id = i;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public int id;
}
```

***`ObjectType2.java`***:

```
package com.sample;

public class ObjectType12 {
  public ObjectType2(int i) {
    super();
    this.id = i;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public int id;
}
```

I get a syntax error from the Drools Eclipse plugin:

```
object1 cannot be resolved.
object2 cannot be resolved.
```

If I change the `or` in the rule LHS to `and`, the error goes away.

I am using Drools 6.2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricky part is how Drools deals with `or` operands between patterns. In your example, Drools will decompose your rule into 2 independent rules:

```
rule "Rule1_A"
when
     object1: ObjectType1( id == 1)
then
    System.out.println(object1.getId());
    System.out.println(object2.getId());
end


rule "Rule1_B"
when
     object2: ObjectType2( id == 2)
then
    System.out.println(object1.getId());
    System.out.println(object2.getId());
end
```

As you can see, the error becomes now more evident.

A side-effect of the way Drools deals with `or` is also that there is no short-circuit in this operation: if both objects are present in your session, the rule will be executed twice.

Hope it helps,

Comment: So, does that mean there is no way to check which facts triggered the rule ? Also, on a side note, regarding the statement `if both objects are present in your session, the rule will be executed twice.`, is there any way to prevent this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the easiest way to prevent it is to create 2 explicit rules: `(A and !B)` and `(!A and B)`.

Comment: And if you want to be purist, if you have an `or` between your patterns, it should mean that the logic you want to execute doesn't depend on which condition was true ;)

Comment: Could you please confirm if the solution given in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40672916/1925388) will work ?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this answer by Esteban](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40649326/1925388), it is not possible to bind variables this way.

Instead, what we can do is create a wrapper class which will contain an object each of the various different datatypes needed to be matched:

```
public class ObjectType {
  ObjectType1 ob1;
  ObjectType2 ob2;

  // setters and getters
}
```

Now, if we wanted to insert an object of, say, `ObjectType1` into the knowledge session:

```
ObjectType1 object1 = new ObjectType1();
kSession.insert(object1);
```

we could instead set `ObjectType.ob1` to reference `object1`, and then insert the new `ObjectType` object into the session:

```
ObjectType1 object1  = new ObjectType1();
ObjectType object = new ObjectType();
object.setOb1(object1);
kSession.insert(object);
```

Now in the rules file, we'd need to match an object of type `ObjectType1` with `ObjectType(getOb1() != null)` rather than `ObjectType1()`:

```
rule "Rule1"
    when
         object: ( ObjectType( ob1 != null && ob1.getId() == 1 ) or
                   ObjectType( ob2 != null && ob2.getId() == 2 ) )
    then
        if ( object.getOb1() != null )
        {
          System.out.println(object.getOb1().getId());
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println(object.getOb2().getId());
        }
end
```